# Approximating a simple function of 6 variables as any function of 2 compositions of them

Tags: taylor-expansion, approximation

I'm not sure if what I ask is feasible nor into what theory or formalism to look in order to solve or find a satisfactory ansatz for it (or the tags to add here -- any corrections are welcome), but consider the simple expression

\begin{equation}
A(c,d,\alpha,\beta,x,y):=cd(\alpha x+\beta y).
\end{equation}

Is there a way to approximate it (with regard to some hypothetical precision or constraints) as a function which depends on the variables $c,d,\alpha,\beta,x,y$ only through the combinations $q=c^2(\alpha^2+\beta^2)$ and $r=d^2(x^2+y^2)$?

That is, is there a way to explicitly find $f$ such that

\begin{equation}
cd(\alpha x+\beta y) \approx f(q,r)
\end{equation}
?

There is no necessity for arbitrarily high precision (for instance, a proximity of 50% to the real value of $A$ would be acceptable -- actually, the order of magnitude is all I need), but, obviously, the method has to make 'analytical sense' and be well defined.

In principle, it can be assumed that  $-1<c,d,\alpha,\beta,x,y<1$.

Comment: What are $c$ and $d$?

Comment: @tomi I'm sorry, it was a confusion of mine. I removed them. Thank you!

Comment: @tomi Actually, $c,d$ were necessary and the question as a whole was wrongly written. Now I have fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

$q=c^2(\alpha^2+\beta^2)$ and $r=d^2(x^2+y^2)$

Want $cd(\alpha x+\beta y) \approx f(q,r)$

Note that $qr=c^2d^2(\alpha^2+\beta^2)(x^2+y^2)$

$qr=c^2d^2(\alpha^2x^2+\alpha^2y^2+\beta^2x^2+\beta^2y^2)$

$qr=c^2d^2(\alpha^2x^2+2\alpha x \beta y + \beta^2y^2+\alpha^2y^2-2\alpha x \beta y+\beta^2x^2)$

$qr=c^2d^2(\alpha x+\beta y)^2 + c^2d^2 (\alpha y-\beta x)^2$

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer, I have upvoted it. In principle, I think this has two problems (if I have understood the implications of your idea): (1) I need the approximation to retain the sign of $cd(\alpha x + \beta y)$, which would be a problem having to take $\sqrt{qr}$, and (2) Something like $O(\alpha y - \beta x) \leq O(\alpha x + \beta y)$ would need to be assured for the approximation to be acceptable.

Comment: Of course that (as I realize now) to naturally retain the sign of my initial expression seems impossible since $q$ and $r$ are strictly positive.

Comment: Yes, I agree there are problems with this approach!